# MagicalRecord not building when pulling pod with Cocoapods v1.0.x

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, magicalrecord

I have been using MagicalRecord in one of my projects.  Up until recently, I had been using Cocoapods v0.39.0 to pull down my pods.  When v1.0.0 of Cocoapods was released, I, along with my team, updated to that newer version.  Ever since then, MagicalRecord is not building anymore.

Specifically, there is an error in `MagicalImportFunctions.h`.

```
'MagicalRecord/MagicalRecordXcode7CompatibilityMacros.h' file not found
```

I am not very familiar with what happens behind the scenes when using Cocoapods, so I am unsure as to why this is all of a sudden happening.  If there is anything I need to provide here to help debug this problem, I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles when you use magicalrecord 3.0
Which is not available on cocopods but you could do:
  pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord', :branch => 'release/3.0'
Which is also needed to get it working in xcode 8.

But it seems like magicalrecord is discontinued, last update 4 months ago.

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunate.  Honestly, v3.0 hasn't been updated in 5 months, compared to the version that is currently in master, which was last updated in April of this year.  On top of that, there seems to be some syntactical changes in v3.0 that I can't find documentation for.

As such, I've already decided to just stick with v2.3.2 and ended up downgrading my Cocoapods to v0.39.0.